# The order of work with git

Tags: git, repository

I would like to ask about the proper order of work with GIT. First I'm using `git clone <url>`, next I'm doing my work on repository and my question is about the "finish". I'm doing `git add <files>` and `git commit -m <comment>` and I want to push it on the remote repo. So what should i do first,`git pull` or something else? First `git pull` and then `git push?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to `git push` if the remote received commits since you last did `git pull`. So yeah, `git pull` before you `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, somebody might have made changes and pushed them to the repository. In this case, it is up to you to merge the changes with yours. So first pull the changes from the remote repository and merge, then commit and push the merged revision.

But if noone else has pushed new changes to the remote repository (all remote heads are known locally), you should be able to just push your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` before you can `git push`.

In general, `git pull --rebase` should be preferred, as it will create linear history. Naked `git pull` will automatically create merge commits, which tend to confuse most people (this is also known as "diamond-shaped" history). If more than one person does it, it can be very difficult to analyze what really happened.

Both `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` can create merge conflicts, which can be resolved with `git mergetool`.